# OpenSSL SHA256 testing

Tags: ssl, openssl, pound

I'm having an issue testing a hardened SSL configuration for [pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound).

One of the requirements is for the inclusion of **AES[128|256]-SHA256** ciphers, along with strict ordering of preference. I've installed *OpenSSL 1.0.1c-fips* on CentOS 6 (via the [IUS](http://iuscommunity.org/) repos), and rebuilt pound against it (along with a [patch for order honouring](http://jonaspasche.com/pound/)).

My pound cipher configuration contains six ciphers, and reads:

```
Ciphers "RC4-SHA:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA"
SSLHonorCipherOrder 1
```

On my local machine (*Ubuntu 12.04, running OpenSSL 1.0.1*), I have a [script](https://gist.github.com/3654892) which tests every cipher locally supported against the website, and reports the results. The abbreviated output is:

```
~$ ciphertest.sh x.x.x.x:443 | grep YES
Testing AES256-SHA...YES
Testing DES-CBC3-SHA...YES
Testing AES128-SHA...YES
Testing RC4-SHA...YES
```

You can see the SHA256 ciphers are not working. However I can confirm my local OpenSSL does have AES256-SHA256 support:

```
~$ openssl ciphers -v | grep ^AES256-SHA256
AES256-SHA256           TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
```

I thought this was a configuration issue, until I ran a [ssllabs.com](http://ssllabs.com) test, which reports all 6 ciphers fine:

[image]

So can anyone explain **why my openssl tests are failing to connect using SHA256 ciphers?**

Comment: Well I'm not sure about your situation, and it's even harder to say given that you've built software with multiple patches and then asking why they don't work as intended, however one thing to keep in mind is that to my knowledge there's no RC4 ciphers allowed by fips 140-2, and SSL 2 and 3 should both be disabled.

Comment: What's the output if you skip the script and directly run `echo -n | openssl s_client -cipher "AES256-SHA256" -connect $SERVER 2>&1` ?